# Acesso negado para impressão de iframe no Firefox

Tags: javascript, iframe, firefox

Eu tenho um sistema onde preciso imprimir um PDF ao clicar no botão.

A url é construída de acordo com o ID da remessa, então dinamicamente, eu uso um iframe que carregará os dados e, quando carregado, eu chamo uma função para imprimir o que está no `iframe`.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
$scope.imprimir = function imprimir (protocolo_id) {

    if (imprimir.carregando) return;

    var url_protocolo = '/protocolos/imprimir/' + protocolo_id;

    imprimir.carregando = true;

    angular.element('#imprimir_protocolo').attr('src', url_protocolo).on('load', function () {

        var frame = $window.frames['imprimir_protocolo'];

        frame.focus();

        frame.print();


        delete imprimir.carregando;

        $scope.$apply();
    })
}
```

Na linha onde eu faço a chamada de `frame.focus()`, quando utilizo o Firefox, está aparecendo o seguinte erro:

> Permission denied to access property "print"

Answer (score 1):

Não se pode executar alguns scripts em um iframe diretamente, você pode tentar usar `contentWindow`:

```
var cw = frame.contentWindow;
cw.focus();
cw.print();
```

Se estiver em dominios diferentes ou protocolos diferentes talves não seja acessivel ainda, então pode tentar injetar uma função dentro do iframe, algo como:

```
<script>
function printPage() {
    window.focus();
    window.print();
}
</script>
```

E chamar:

```
frame.contentWindow.printPage();
```

Faz algum tempo que não trabalho com isto, mas me lembro que cada navegador tinha um comportamento e variava bastante.

Comment: Aff, esse problema de comportar diferente em cada navegador! To quase pensando em deixar um link abrindo o PDF :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters acho um bom caminho, ainda mais para mobiles :)